# Using awk variable in gsub to count occurrences in line

Tags: awk, gsub

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong here

```
echo "T T A T T T" | awk '{print $4"\t"gsub(/$4/,"")}'

T   0
```

I'm trying to get this result

```
echo "T T A T T T" | awk '{print $4"\t"gsub(/T/,"")}'

T   5
```

Thanks

Comment: `echo "T T A T T T" | awk '{print $4"\t"gsub($4,"")}'` (you simply want `$4` to be treated as a string to be matched (a dynamic regex), not an actual regex between `/.../` where `'$'` has special meaning)

Comment: See [GNU Awk User's Guide - 3.6 Using Dynamic Regexps](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Computed-Regexps.html#Computed-Regexps)

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from the comments, you don't want to enclose `$4` in `/../` as you would do with a constant regex. (`'$'` has special meaning) You simply want to use `$4` so it will be treated as a dynamic regex, e.g.

```
awk '{print $4"\t"gsub($4,"")}'
```

For discussion of using dynamic regexes, see [GNU Awk User's Guide - 3.6 Using Dynamic Regexps](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Computed-Regexps.html#Computed-Regexps)

**Example Use/Output**

You can then obtain the desired output, e.g.

```
$ echo "T T A T T T" | awk '{print $4"\t"gsub($4,"")}'
T       5
```